# How do I need to call string overload for ngxs selectSnapshot?

Tags: angular, ngxs

eranshmil commented on [this issue](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/632), and provided solution for breaking circular dependecy by using string overload for selectSnapshot.

But I can't seem to make it work properly, here's [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnwuey)

It says `selectorFn is not a function`, so I guess it tries to call a function, but I'am passing string.

How do I call selectSnapshot to use it's another overload that uses string as an argument?

Comment: How are you looking to use the value? Do you just want the current value without subscribing to the state changes? 
Are you saying `this.store.selectSnapshot(x => x.game.somewhat)` is not what you are after?

Comment: I was looking for a way to use store selectors without running into circular dependency. My selectors have pretty complex logic, so selecting just slice of state is not what am I loking for